# rails routing member and non-member nesting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Two quite similar routing settings really is confusing.

```
resources :authors do
  resources :books
end
```

and

```
resources :authors do
  member do
    resources :books
  end
end
```

As we all know, rails will generate the following routings :

```
writer_book   GET  /writers/:writer_id/books/:id(.:format)   books#show
```

and

```
book          GET    /writers/:id/books/:id(.:format)        books#show
```

How is this member option useful? 
One can just not using member option and set params[:writer_id] in books_controller and  be done with it right?
Does this will have a bad affect when the application gets bigger? What are the consequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `member` and `collection` methods are meant to add additional RESTful actions to resources

```
resources :writers do
  member do
    post :favorite
  end

  collection do
    get :unpublished
  end
end
```

They are not intended for nesting resources

```
# bad
resources :writers do
  member do
    resources :books
  end
end

# good
resources :writers do
  resources :books
end
```

> What are the consequences?

Using member here will result in the route

```
GET    /writers/:id/books/:id(.:format)
```

Which means that the `id` param is ambigous! It could be either the id of the book or the author! Not good! Not using `member` would give us `params[:writer_id]` which we can use to fetch the parent record.

```
GET  /writers/:writer_id/books/:id(.:format)   books#show
```

See:

- [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)